# Drawing on image iphone using cocos2d-iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating *Drawing app for ipad using cocos2d-iphone*
its using *CCRenderTexture* for drawing.
I am able to take screenshot of my drawing and saving it to application document directory.

but now I want to load this as my background image to draw over it,and can change the image,so basically I want to merge my image with my render texture I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954936/cocos2d-adding-a-background-image-to-a-layer)
but image is appearing below my rendertexture (with z=-1), I am not able to figure it out.
Is there any way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Wait, if the background image is appearing below the render texture, isn't that how it is supposed to be? (Background = Below things)

Comment: see my question.it may help you

Comment: @Ramshad can u plz post some link to your question.I didn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is how i solved my problem

Step 1> created my RenderTexture

```
renderTexture = [[CCRendertexture alloc]initWithWidth:self.contentSize.width height:self.contentSize.height pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
renderTexture.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
renderTexture.position = ccp(width*0.5,height*0.5f);
```

Step 2> Created CCSprite with background image

```
CCSprite *bgImage = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:myImage.CGImage key:imgkey];
bgImage.position = ccp(width*0.5f,height*o.5f);
```

Step3> This is important part in this

```
[renderTexture begin];
[bgImage visit];
[renderTexture end];

[self addChild:renderTexture]; // added to my layer as child
```

this tutorial helped me http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

I hope this will be helpful for someone